# How to merge several csv files averaging fields?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have several csv files name file1, file2, file3, etc. They all look like this (exactly identical, only the floats change):

```
filename,    column1,  column2, ... columnN
asdfasd.jpg   23.23,    21.24,        1e-06
ersdadfsd.jpg 223.23,   1.23,         1
assd.jpg      23.23,    1e-08,       232.1
...
```

I would like to get an indentical looking table in which all fields contain the mean. How can this be done in an efficient way?

Comment: Are you looking for the average for each row from column1 through columnN, or the average of each column?

Comment: None, I am looking for a cell by cell average. So the final table will have the same dimensions in terms of rows and columns.

Comment: Ah, my apologies. Missed the point that the filename column does not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
all_csv = []
for one_file in list_of_file:
    all_csv.append(pd.read_csv(one_file))
df = pd.concat(all_csv).groupby('filename').mean()
```

should do want you want.

As example, with two csv:

```py
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['a', 'b'], 'v1': [1, 2,], 'v2': [3, 4]}) # your first csv
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['a', 'b'], 'v1': [5, 6,], 'v2': [7, 8]}) # your second csv
>>> df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2])
>>> df3
  name  v1  v2
0    a   1   3
1    b   2   4
0    a   5   7
1    b   6   8
>>> df3.groupby('name').mean() 
# create sub dataframe with only the same name values (a and b) and 
# the mean compute the mean on this sub dataframe column by column.
```